# Proxy (or some sort of) between firebase backend and mobile/web applications

Tags: firebase, web-applications, proxy, google-cloud-functions, mobile-application

I want to create some sort of proxy between my android/web application plus the firebase backend so that, every time an android/web application sends a request, I  catch that request and create a log with it in the proxy.

Then, the proxy must redirect that request to Firebase, receive the response from the request and send it to the application.

It is possible to do something like this? It is possible to redirect requests from applications to an external system before the request reaches Firebase?

**Example:**

```
Mobile Application <---> Proxy (log) <---> Firebase
```

I've seen that this can be achieved by creating a cloud function that receives the request from the application and redirects it (through an HTTP request) to the external system.

Then the external system sends the HTTP request (also through an HTTP request) to Firebase, receives the response, and sends it to the application.

It this a good solution? Or is there and easier solution?